# ERROR: Multiple annotations found at this line: - The method register(EmployeeDetails) is undefined for the type HttpSession

Tags: java, jsp

Please help me to correct the error that I am getting. Also please suggest a site or example program for Hibernate web application.

Error is on `session.register(obj);` in `register.jsp`

**register.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.acc.emp.session.SessionDetails"%>

<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.acc.emp_details.EmployeeDetails">  
</jsp:useBean>  

<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head> 
<body>
<%
int i=session.register(obj);
if(i>0)
out.print("You are successfully registered");

%>
</body>
</html>
```

**SessionDetails.java**

```
package com.acc.emp.session;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.acc.emp_details.EmployeeDetails;

public class SessionDetails {
    public static int register(EmployeeDetails emp){
        int i = 0;
        Session session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        t.begin();
        session.save(emp);
        t.commit();
        session.close();
        return i;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeDetails.java**

```
package com.acc.emp_details;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class EmployeeDetails {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int indexing;
    private String empName;
    private String EmpDetails;
    private String jiraDetails;
    private String trainings;
    private String attendaceDetails;

    public EmployeeDetails(){}

    public EmployeeDetails(String empName,String EmpDetails, String jiraDetails,String trainings,String attendaceDetails){
        this.empName = empName;
        this.EmpDetails = EmpDetails;
        this.jiraDetails =jiraDetails;
        this.trainings = trainings;
        this.attendaceDetails = attendaceDetails;
    }
    public int getIndexing() {
        return indexing;
    }
    public void setIndexing(int indexing) {
        this.indexing = indexing;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public String getEmpDetails() {
        return EmpDetails;
    }
    public void setEmpDetails(String empDetails) {
        EmpDetails = empDetails;
    }
    public String getJiraDetails() {
        return jiraDetails;
    }
    public void setJiraDetails(String jiraDetails) {
        this.jiraDetails = jiraDetails;
    }
    public String getTrainings() {
        return trainings;
    }
    public void setTrainings(String trainings) {
        this.trainings = trainings;
    }
    public String getAttendaceDetails() {
        return attendaceDetails;
    }
    public void setAttendaceDetails(String attendaceDetails) {
        this.attendaceDetails = attendaceDetails;
    }   
}
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="register.jsp" method="post">  
Name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br><br/>  
Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br><br/>  
Email ID:<input type="text" name="email"/><br><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="register"/>"  

</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please paste your code rather than attaching a screenshot.